# Generating permutations in OCaml

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, ocaml

```
open Core.Std;;


let print aofa =
    let s1 = ( Array.length aofa ) - 1 in
    for i = 0 to s1 do
        for j = 0 to (Array.length aofa.(i)) - 1 do
            printf "%d " aofa.(i).(j);
        done;
        printf "\n";
    done;
;;


let rec fact i =
    if i <= 1 then 1 else i * fact (i - 1)
;;

let rec permutations ints =
    let length = Array.length ints in

    if length < 2 then
        [|ints|]
    else begin
        let total = fact length in

        let result = Array.create total (Array.create length 0) in
        for i = 0 to total - 1 do
            result.(i) <- Array.create length 0
        done;

        let block_size = total / length in
        for i = 1 to length do
            let rest = Array.append (Array.sub ints 0 (i - 1)) (Array.sub ints i (length - i)) in
            let rights = permutations rest in
            for r = 0 to (Array.length rights) - 1 do
                let n = Array.append [|Array.get ints (i - 1) |] rights.(r) in
                result.((i - 1) * block_size + r) <- n
            done;
        done;

        result
    end
;;


let () =
    let aofa = permutations [|1; 2; 3|] in
    print aofa;
;;
```

And result:

```
1 2 3 
1 3 2 
2 1 3 
2 3 1 
3 1 2 
3 2 1
```

**UPD:**

As first step, I wrote naive implementaion on python and then make version in OCaml

```
def permutations(s):
    if len(s) > 1:
        for i, v in enumerate(s):
            for p in permutations(s[0: i] + s[i+1:]):
                yield [v] + p
    else:
        yield s


def main():
    for p in permutations([1, 2, 3]):
        print(p)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is totally imperative. In some cases (probably in most) it's faster, but this not the best way to use OCaml :) Here is my solution in functional style:

Printing the list of lists can be done by iterating over list of lists:

```fs
let print lst =
  List.iter (fun l ->
      List.map string_of_int l
      |> String.concat " "
      |> print_endline
    ) lst
```

Next recursive function does:

- Selects head element of the list and makes it heading element of the resulting list

  Recursively calls itself on the list of all previous elements (minus resulting subset) + tail.

```fs
let rec permutations result other = function
  | [] -> [result]
  | hd :: tl ->
    let r = permutations (hd :: result) [] (other @ tl) in
    if tl <> [] then
      r @ permutations result (hd :: other) tl
    else
      r
```

All together. Initial result is empty and the stored list of previous elements is also empty:

```fs
let () =
  permutations [] [] [1; 2; 3]
  |> print
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer.

Comment: My code is first try to write something longer than "hello world" in OCaml, so I was happy to see it works :)

Thanks for your review!

Comment: Btw, how works "@"?

Comment: "@" concatenates two lists, see pervasives.mli in OCaml library. E.g.:

    [1; 2] @ [3; 4] → [1; 2; 3; 4]

This is not tail-recursive and has complexity O(n) so actually you should use it carefully.

Comment: May be Array more suitable in this case, than List?